# Array get specific field

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have a variable in WordPress (using Visual Composer plugin template)

```
$posts_query = $settings['posts_query']
```

and when i print_r

```
print_r($posts_query);
```

results on this:

```
size:4|order_by:date|post_type:donation_slider|post_status:publish
```

How can i get the field post_type?

I tried with `$posts_query['post_type']` but it just shows letter "s" or `$posts_query->post_type;` it shows blank!

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why the tag `R`?

Comment: Can you do `var_dump($posts_query)`? I suspect it's a string, not an array.

Comment: Probably, it's a string variable, i am newbe on php

here is the result  of var_dump 

string(66)

Answer (score 1):

This is an atypical situation, and an atypical way to store information.  It looks like someone decided to invent their own [serialization](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) storage (storing an array in a string).

To access the information you want, you'll need to manipulate the string into the various array components, using [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

Here's some code to get you started:

```
// $posts_query is equal to "size:4|order_by:date|post_type:donation_slider|post_status:publish"

$parts = explode('|', $posts_query);
// now parts is an array: ['size:4', 'order_by:date', 'post_type:donation_slider', 'post_status:publish'
$array = [];

// loop over the exploded parts
foreach( $parts AS $part ) {
    // split the sub-parts apart
    $split = explode(':', $part);
    // glue it into a proper associative array
    $array[$split[0]] = $split[1];
}
```

Now you have an array that should look like this:

```
array(
    'size'        => 4,
    'order_by'    => 'date',
    'post_type'   => 'donation_slider',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
)
```

Which you can access each separate part like so:

```
$post_type = $array[ 'post_type']; // returns "donation_slider"
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know WordPress very well but the native PHP way to do this is like this:

```
$posts_query = 'size:4|order_by:date|post_type:donation_slider|post_status:publish';

foreach( explode( '|', $posts_query ) as $pairs )
{
    if( explode( ':', $pairs )[0] === 'post_type' )
    {
        echo explode( ':', $pairs )[1];
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an imploded string. The elements are separated by `|`, and keys and values are separated by `:`. You can use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to create the array you want:

```
$array = [];
foreach( explode($posts_query, '|') as $keyVal) {
  $tmp = explode($keyVal, ':');
  $array[$tmp[0]] = $tmp[1];
}
```

Then you can use array like you did in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution:

```
    $post_type_query = explode("|", $posts_query);  
    $post_type  = str_replace("post_type:","",$post_type_query[2]);
```

and it print the value of post_type.

Thank you so much for your help guys, i appreciate that!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution:

It appears that `$posts_query` is a string so accessing it like an array won't pull out the `'post_type'`.

You could try using this function (Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), this makes a new array out of `$posts_query` with `|` being the separator between data fields and `:` being the separator between key and value. Then you can get `post_type` like `$parsed_posts_query['post_type']` as shown.

```
function explode_with_keys($delim1,$delim2,$inputstring)
{
    $firstarr = explode($delim1,$inputstring);
    $finalarr = array();
    foreach($firstarr as $set)
    {
        $setarr = explode($delim2,$set);
        $finalarr[$setarr[0]] = $setarr[1];
    }
    return $finalarr;
}

$parsed_posts_query = explode_with_keys("|",":",$posts_query);
print_r($parsed_posts_query['post_type']);
```